# how to evaluate math expression with variables in vba?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Consider the following expression "x*y+3".

How can i evaluate this when x & y will be defined by the user in run time. 
This is for a small data base in access 2013 for my work place.
thank you.

Comment: Do you mean users will define x and y and store them in variables.  Have you created the code to grab the data and store the data in a variable?  This isn't a "write code for me" site.  What have you tried?

Comment: What method do you have in mind to allow the user to submit values for `x` and `y`?  Then what do you want to do with the computed value?

Comment: user input will be made through access form and be saved to data base, so when i run the code it will take these values.

Answer (score 1):

You may try Eval, but you will have to be very careful with string processing to put arguments properly. Here is a code sample:

```
Sub TestEval()
    Dim Expr As String

    Expr = "x*y+2"
    Expr = Replace(Expr, "x", "3")
    Expr = Replace(Expr, "y", "4")

    Debug.Print Eval(Expr)  'prints 14
End Sub
```